# error/Stream Closed in BufferedReader

Tags: java, loops, bufferedreader, file-handling

i have this method in my program:

```
public void View() throws IOException{
        File original=new File("C:\\voters.txt");
        BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(original));

        vNum=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter voters ID: ");
        String line;
        while((line=read.readLine())!=null){

            String info[]=line.split("/");

            if(info[1].matches(vNum)){
                all="\t\t\t\t-------VOTERS INFORMATION-------\t\t\t\t\n\n"
                        +"NAME: "+info[2]+"\tAGE: "+info[3]
                        +"\nGENDER: "+info[4]+"DATE OF BIRTH: "+info[5]
                        +"\nPLACE OF BIRTH: "+info[6]+"\tPLACE OF BIRTH: "+info[7]
                        +"\nCIVIL STATUS: "+info[8]+"\tCITIZENSHIP: "+info[9]
                        +"\nPROFESSION/OCCUPATION: "+info[10]+"\tVOTERS NUMBER: "+info[1]
                        +"\nFATHER'S NAME: "+info[11]+"\nMOTHER'S NAME: "+info[12];

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(all));
                break;
            }

            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voter doesn't exit");
            }

            read.close();
        }
    }
```

but ever time i execute this method, there it always stop and an error will appear. it says Stream Closed. here is it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedReader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at lozada.My_Voting_System_Official.View(My_Voting_System_Official.java:231)
    at lozada.My_Voting_System_Official.Menu(My_Voting_System_Official.java:73)
    at lozada.My_Voting_System_Official.main(My_Voting_System_Official.java:26)
```

i don't really know what is the problem because most of my methods in my programs does have `while((line=read.readLine())!=null)` and those methods works. only this method won't work. also, the text file exist. please please help

Comment: The `read.close();` is just firing. You might want to re-read your code. It is closing the while loop.

Comment: @Scar oh. yes i didn't notice that. thank you so much :)

Comment: @Scar can i ask why does my error message appear twice??